# Add Elasticsearch index to existing Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

Prerequisite:

- Elasticsearch is up and running
- Database is already filled with data
- Rails models look like

  ```
  class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
    include Elasticsearch::Model
    include Elasticsearch::Model::Callbacks
  end
  ```

Question: **What is the correct way to index the models?**

My assumption:

1. Execute the following rake task for every model I want to add to elasticsearch, but only the very first time

> bundle exec rake environment elasticsearch:import:model
>   CLASS='Customer'

2. I add "Customer.import" to the very bottom of the models file to insure that the models get indexed every time I start my rails application.

Is that enough? Will this work, even if I change the mappings of the model or if I add a new field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding elasticsearch do existing model:

- First adding the `callbacks module` will take care of indexing any new records or updating existing records you have already added it `include Elasticsearch::Model::Callbacks`
- Second, you need to specify which fields are you going to index in that model by defining the following method at your model `as_indexed_json`

  `def as_indexed_json(options={})
     as_json(
       only: [:first_name, :last_name, :address],
       include: [products: { only: :name }]
    )
  end`

  [This is a very good article explainging everything](http://www.codinginthecrease.com/news_article/show/409843) and of course everytime you need to index a new field, you need to updated the `as_indexed_json` method and also run the rake task. to rebuild the indexes agaain.
- Third to index the data you have it already before installing elasticsearch you can just create a rake task to to call `import` method on that `model` to re-index or create a new index for that model.